# ver a quantidade de vezes que um numero troca de posição em c++ usando BubbleSort

Tags: c++, classificação, bubblesort

Alguém poderia dar um exemplo de como eu faria isso? Tipo, um vetor de tamanho 5, com os seguintes números: 33,64,21,85 e 15. Gostaria de saber quantas vezes ele compara os números e realiza a troca, deixando em ordem crescente: 15,21,33,64 e 85, ai ele voltaria tipo o valor de 9 iterações eu acho.

```
while(vet[j]>vet[j+1]){
        contador++;
        if(vet[j]>vet[j+1]){    
        aux=vet[j];             
        vet[j]=vet[j+1];        
        vet[j+1]=aux;           

      }
       }
     }
   }
   cout<<"Iteracoes: "<< contador<<endl;
```

Existe algum erro nesse while?

Comment: Você implementou o código do bubblesort em C++? Ficaria mais fácil de explicar se você colocasse o seu código na pergunta, mas resumidamente, basta inicializar um contador com zero antes das iterações e incrementa-lo a cada troca realizada.